# Handle new windows in Cefsharp (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm new to cefsharp and i cant seem to wrap my head around how I'd be able to handle popups in the simplest manner. These are popups such as when the page requests a new tab, or even when a confirm/alert is fired.
Everything is fine and all with the default settings, but I want the popup's title bar to show a predefined text, like for instance my app's name. By default it shows the url which requested the popup and i don't want that. Besides that, everything can remain as it is.
Any idea how i could achieve this?

Comment: Start by reading the general usage guide https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#handlers

Comment: Setting the pop-up window title is quite complex, would require native method calls. Search the source for SetWindowText

Comment: would be more feasible instead if i just create my own dialog boxes?